# Javascript - Loop through nested object

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have 1 array with multiple object and an object. How do i find and return the data matching that object. Here is an illustration of my code.

```js
const cars = [{model:"honda", color:"black", features:[{title:"fast",speed:"100mph"}]}]

const feature = {id:1,title:"fast",speed:"100mph"} 

const match = cars.filter(car => car.features.includes(feature))
```

This should return

```js
{model:"honda", color:"black", features:[{title:"fast",speed:"100mph"}]}
```

but it does not and not sure why. Can someone help?

Comment: You mean to return an object instead an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use [`Array.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) for this purpose as you can't compare two objects for equality (you will only get true if they refer to the *same* object). Instead you could use [`Array.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and [`Array.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) to see if any `features` object has all its key/value pairs duplicated in `feature`:

```js
const cars = [{
  model: "honda",
  color: "black",
  features: [{
    title: "fast",
    speed: "100mph"
  }]
}];
const feature = {
  id: 1,
  title: "fast",
  speed: "100mph"
};

const match = cars.filter(car => car.features.some(f => Object.keys(f).every(k => f[k] == feature[k])));

console.log(match);
```

Comment: From OP's expected result, this looks like more of a `find` operation than `filter`. I could be wrong though

Comment: @Phil I did consider that, but there's only value in each of the `cars` and `features` arrays so it's not clear whether that would give the desired result, as it seems that you could have another car which had a feature of `{title:"fast",speed:"100mph"}`